# Java web projects with good code

Tags: java, web

I need some good real Java web projects to watch code on Github or Bitbucket and learn how to work with database (Hibernate, JDBC), Spring, Servlet etc. There are a lot of theory in the internet but I want to see more practice. Do you have some to suggest?

Comment: tell me exactly what do you want.

Comment: If you are not getting anything on google just search on youtube you ll get relevant videos

Comment: I don't need tutorials, I just need some real projects to watch code.

Comment: So you're not on the right place .

Comment: by watching code you'll learn nothing. if you want to learn Hibernate, jdbc, ... the official pages have pretty good documentations, mostly with examples, and if those are not sufficient, there are tons of books out there.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Spring Pet Clinic on Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/)

Comment: Thank you. It is a good example of what I want to find.

Answer (score 0):

When i was looking for best practices for developing EAR project, i found out some articles that might be helpful:

[Design patterns Java EE 6 with JSF / EJB / JPA](http://miageprojet2.unice.fr/index.php?title=Intranet_de_Michel_Buffa/Design_Patterns_Java_EE_6/Design_patterns_Java_EE_6_with_JSF_%2F%2F_EJB_%2F%2F_JPA):

[How to design clean business tier with EJB and JPA](http://palkonyves.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-design-clean-business-tier-with.html)

And also rememebr to get to know with J2EE design patterns:

[Core J2EE Pattern Catalog](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/)

Comment: keep in mind: 'Last Updated:
January 29, 2006 8:54 PM '